# Ansible, jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-playbook

Подскажите, не могу понять. Для теста быстро набросал, опыта 0.
Файл .j2:

```
{% for group in groups['all'] %}
Host {{ group }}
User {{ ansible_user }}
{% endfor %}
```

Файл hosts:

```
[test1]
localhost1 ansible_host=localhost ansible_host_ip=127.0.0.1 ansible_user=arch1 ansible_connection=local
localhost2 ansible_host=localhost ansible_host_ip=127.0.0.2 ansible_user=test ansible_connection=local
localhost3 ansible_host=localhost ansible_host_ip=127.0.0.3 ansible_user=test ansible_connection=local
[test2]
localhost4 ansible_host=localhost ansible_host_ip=127.0.0.4 ansible_user=root1 ansible_connection=local
```

Файл .yml:

```
---
- name: Test SSH create
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update Test SSH Jinja2
      template:
        src: /etc/ansible/temlates/ssh_test.j2
        dest: /etc/ansible/test
```

И вывод:

```
Host localhost1
User test
Host localhost2
User test
Host localhost3
User test
Host localhost4
User test
```

Почему ansible_user всегда одинаковый? Почему он не проставяет их по очереди? Как я понял это потому что переменная ansible_user, берется с того хоста, на котором создается конфиг. Как можно это поправить, без использования модуля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что мне нужно было, не очевидно было как указывать переменные.

```
{% for group in groups['all'] %}    
Host {{ hostvars[group]['inventory_hostname'] }}
         HostName {{ hostvars[group]['inventory_hostname'] }}
         User {{ hostvars[group]['ansible_user'] }}
{% endfor %}
```